# Url append in apache http with weblogic plugin

Tags: apache, http, webserver, reverse-proxy, weblogic11g

I am configuring a apache http server with weblogic plugin where I want to add different environments to be forwarded to different weblogic url.

for e.g.

The proxy should work like this, where the weblogic-hosts are containers and are not accessible from outside.

```
http://apache-host:80/qa/console --> http://weblogic-host1:7001/console
http://apache-host:80/qa/app1 --> http://weblogic-host1:7001/app1

http://apache-host:80/dev/console --> http://weblogic-host2:7001/console
http://apache-host:80/dev/app1 --> http://weblogic-host2:7001/app1
```

Can anyone give some clue how to extend my below http configs ?

```
<VirtualHost apachhe-host:80>
 <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicHost weblogic-host1
    WebLogicPort 7001
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<Location /console>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicHost weblogic-host1
    WeblogicPort 7001
    WLSRequest On
</Location>
```

I am able to access the page `http://apache-host:80/qa/console` with below config:

```
<VirtualHost apache-host:80>
 <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicHost weblogic-host1
    WebLogicPort 7001
    MatchExpression *.*
  </IfModule>
<LocationMatch /qa/console>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicHost weblogic-host1
    WebLogicPort 7001
    WLSRequest On
    ProxyPass http://weblogic-host1:7001/console
    ProxyPassReverse http://weblogic-host1:7001/console
</LocationMatch>
```

But after logging into the console, its throwing 404:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /console/j_security_check was not found on this server.
```

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `MatchExpression *.*` to `MatchExpression /` resolved the issue.